# How to launch firefox with only one tab or how to close other tabs before opening my tab within my android application?

Tags: android, firefox

I have an android application. I want to launch Firefox to load the url within my app. My problem is Firefox will add a new tab when launching it within my app every time. How do I avoid adding a new tab to load the url?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think that your application can control Firefox behavior. If you launch the intent, Firefox will handle it from there. Unless Firefox has an api which you can use to control the behavior.